# How do I place user's input inside of a method that returns if the person exists?

Tags: python, django, input

I have this code in which I need to use a method that takes the number the person inputs to check if the person exists in the database. The thing is, how do I pass the numbers the person uses to the method?
The numbers are what's called `cuit` in here.

The method works like this:

```
response=get_persona("74013028")
```

The numbers should be the ones the person types. If the person exists, it returns the name and last name like this:

```
response["persona"]["lastname"]["name"]
```

If the person doesn't exist, it has to print that.

Where should I place this piece of code and how do I make it take the input of the user to verify if the person is in the database?

This is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
from django.views import View
from .forms import MonotributoForm
from app.ws_sr_padron import get_persona


class Constancia(View):

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
    
    def post(self,request):

        if request:
            
            form = MonotributoForm(request.POST)
            
            if form.is_valid():
                cuit = form.cleaned_data.get('cuit')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                cuit.save()
                email.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
        else:
             pass 
        
        return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```